# Set Windows command-line terminal title in Python

Tags: python, windows, low-latency

I'm running several instances of a certain Python script on a Windows machine, each from a different directory and using a separate shell windows. Unfortunately Windows gives each of these shell windows the same name:

```
<User>: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - <script.py>
```

Is it possible to set this name to something else through a Python command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62709559/11667949

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This works for Python2.7 under Windows.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA("My New Title")
```

Comment: Or ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("My New Title") for python 3

Comment: How about the reverse? Open an instance of python from command prompt and specify the title of the new python instance.

Comment: For the most portability and independence from cached prototypes on `ctypes.windll` (the worst idea in ctypes), use `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True);` `kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(u"My New Title")`. An `errcheck` function with signature `(result, func, args)` should also be set. It should `raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())` if the result is false (i.e. the call failed), which enables idiomatic Python programming with exceptions instead of crude C error codes.

Comment: There another DIFFERENCE between ctypes and system. The latter will keep 'Command Prompt - "C:\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat" activate <env>' and APPEND the title, whereas ctypes will CLEAR it, so it's better if you have many (narrow?) windows.

Answer (score 57):

On Windows, a simple console command will suffice:

```
from os import system
system("title " + myCoolTitle)
```

Nice and easy.

Comment: I moved the correct answer mark to this answer as it works and has no dependencies

Comment: @Jonathan Jeffrey Harper's answer is better as there are also no dependencies and in addition it doesn't invoke shell.

Comment: The benefit of this answer is the cmd shell's builtin `title` command prepends `Administrator: ` to the title if the user has admin rights.

Comment: Another advantage with this is that it can be preceded with `system("cls")` to clear the window from old clutter.

Comment: What about Linux?

Answer (score 27):

Due to not enough rep I cannot add a comment to the above post - so as a new post.

In **Python 3** you can use:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("My New Title")
```

I edited this answer: please remark, that it now uses SetConsoleTitle**W**, which is the Unicode version of the [SetConsoleTitle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686050(v=vs.85).aspx) function.
This way you can use unicode and no longer have to encode the string/variable to a byte object. You can just replace the argument with the string variable.

Comment: Writing UTF-8 to an ANSI API is nonsense. You'll get mojibake. You should always prefer the native wide-character APIs in Windows programming. The ANSI APIs are all but deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. You are correct, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're only going to be running this on Windows (IOW, there's not a cross-platform way to do this):

1. Download & install the [Win32 extensions for python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)
2. Inside of your script, you can change the title of the console with the [function](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/pywin32/win32console__SetConsoleTitle_meth.html)

   `win32console.SetConsoleTitle("My Awesome App")`

Answer (score 4):

### Comparison of the posted `system()` & `windll`-based methods

tying to add a small quantitative comparison of **latency overheads** associated with two of the posted methods:

```
|>>> from zmq import Stopwatch
|>>> aSWX = Stopwatch()

|>>> from os import system
|>>> aSWX.start();system( 'TITLE os_SHELL_CMD_TITLE_TXT');aSWX.stop()  15149L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();system( 'TITLE os_SHELL_CMD_TITLE_TXT');aSWX.stop()  15347L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();system( 'TITLE os_SHELL_CMD_TITLE_TXT');aSWX.stop()  15000L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();system( 'TITLE os_SHELL_CMD_TITLE_TXT');aSWX.stop()  14674L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();system( 'TITLE os_SHELL_CMD_TITLE_TXT');aSWX.stop()  14774L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();system( 'TITLE os_SHELL_CMD_TITLE_TXT');aSWX.stop()  14551L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();system( 'TITLE os_SHELL_CMD_TITLE_TXT');aSWX.stop()  14633L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();system( 'TITLE os_SHELL_CMD_TITLE_TXT');aSWX.stop()  15202L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();system( 'TITLE os_SHELL_CMD_TITLE_TXT');aSWX.stop()  14889L [us]

|>>> from ctypes import windll
|>>> aSWX.start();windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA('DLL');aSWX.stop()   5767L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA('DLL');aSWX.stop()    643L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA('DLL');aSWX.stop()    573L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA('DLL');aSWX.stop()    749L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA('DLL');aSWX.stop()    689L [us]
|>>> aSWX.start();windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA('DLL');aSWX.stop()    651L [us]
```

In cases, where one might spend about a half of millisecond ( but not some tens of that ) the **`windll.kernel32`** method seems promising and may serve better for an alternative display of a WatchDOG / StateVARs / ProgressLOG / auto-self-diagnostic messages, being efficiently displayed in a soft real-time need, during long running processes.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a way to change the `cmd` window title from within the script.

However, you can set the title when launching the script if you use the [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Comment: This is a nice way to do it as it has no dependencies, however in my case the script only knows the intended window name after it reads a configuration file...

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```py
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW('new title')
```

Or:

```py
import os
os.system('title new title')
```

Comment: YMMV, but I found `ctypes` to be significantly faster than `os.system`.

Answer (score 2):

If [starting the Idle-shell](http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html#command-line-usage) is an option instead of the cmd shell:

```
idle.py [-c command] [-d] [-e] [-s] [-t title] [arg] ...

-c command  run this command
-d          enable debugger
-e          edit mode; arguments are files to be edited
-s          run $IDLESTARTUP or $PYTHONSTARTUP first
-t title    set title of shell window
```

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to change the window title from within any language via outputting a standard escape sequence to the console (stdout).  Here's a working example from a batch file [Change command prompt to only show current directory name](https://superuser.com/a/1365342) however just printing ESC close-bracket 2 semicolon your-title-here BEL (control-G) will do it.  Also an easily adapted PHP example:

```
function windowTitle($title)
  {printf("\033]2;%s\007", $title);}
```

Comment: This is not an answer in python code (which is a requirement of the question). Please ensure your answers have the correct scope to the question.

Comment: @mike_n Irregardless of the comment above, this was useful to me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Using OS module To interact with the terminal

1. Import the library - `import os`
2. Interact with the terminal to change title - `os.system('title your_tile')`

#### Explanation:

So if you open your terminal and type `title your_title` is will change the terminal title to `your_title`
[image: CMD]

In Python the `OS.system()` is used to type into the terminal

This is how you will change title of terminal with Python