# Automatically restart a python if it closes or crashes

Tags: python, batch-file, restart

I have 3 python files, 1.py, 2.py, 3.py and I'm trying to make a bat batch file that restarts my python files in case they break or close for some reason.
I'm trying with the following code, but it is not working very well:

```
@echo off
:Restart
start "1" /wait "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\test\1.py"
start "2" /wait "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\test\2.py"
start "3" /wait "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\test\3.py"
goto Restart
```

my goal is, with just a bat file, to automatically restart any of my 3 files in case any of them close or crash.
if only one of them has closed, restart only it, or if two of them close, restart both, so on

Comment: start them without `/wait` and watch them with `tasklist /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq 1"`

Comment: Closing and crashing are different scenarios. A script will close when it has executed all routines written in it. A script will crash if there is an Exception raised. In the latter case, you must include exception handling and/or logging to keep track. In the former case, it depends whether your scripts run indefinitely (all the time) or close after they have done the job.

Comment: complete answers please

Comment: @Stephan Be clearer, I do not understand much of batch.

Comment: @amanb only when it is forced to close for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just copying-pasting my answer from your another dublicate question ([Batch that monitors and restarts a python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806291/batch-that-monitors-and-restarts-a-python/)):

A combination of an "infinite loop" which is needed in your case and python files will overload your CPU a lot I think. Have a revised piece of code (working only in single file extensions (`*.bat, *.txt`)). See below for something more general.

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

:start_python_files
start "1st" "test1.py"
start "2nd" "test2.py"
start "3rd" "test3.py"

:check_python_files
call:infinite 1st test1.py
call:infinite 2nd test2.py
call:infinite 3rd test3.py
goto:check_python_files

:infinite
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %1 - %2" | findstr /c:PID > nul
rem findstr /c:PID command added above to confirm that tasklist has found the process (errorlevel = 0). If not (errorlevel = 1).
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (start "%1" "%2")
```

Well, this way may last some time, so if a file is closed (~2-3 secs depending on your CPU overload).

Please notify me if it is not working for you. I haven't python installed and I don't know how they are named when they are opened :).

So, now as you have (kindly???) requested complete answers let me explain my code:

- I enable extensions (`setlocal EnableExtensions`) to change `call` command as follows:

> CALL command now accepts labels as the target of the CALL. The syntax
>   is:
>
> CALL :label arguments

<sup>From `call /?` command. You should type it in a fresh cmd for more information</sup>

- I specify the window title with the `start` command, so my code will work. Type `start /?` in a fresh cmd window.
- I `call` the `infinite` subroutine sending to it arguments (window title and filename). These can be accessed with `%1` (first argument) and `%2` (second argument).
- In the `infinite` subroutine, I search for window title (`WINDOWTITLE`) EQUAL (`eq`) to format `window title - filename`. Even if it doesn't exist `tasklist` will return `errorlevel` value `0` with the message:

> INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

As here `PID` string doesn't exist (if it is found it will exist), we put `findstr` to search for it. If found, `errorlevel` will be `0`. Else, it would be `1`.

- If the `errorlevel` is `1`, that means that process not found, which means that the file is closed. So, we reopen it with the arguments sent (`start "window title (%1)" "filename (%2)"`).
- As we have `call`ed the `infinite` subroutine, after its end, we will return to `check_python_files` subroutine doing all of these above infinitely, until user termination or computer shutdown.

As later discussed in chat, when we run python files standardly (with `start "window title"`) window title will be the full path to `python.exe` file. I found a way to fix it: `start` the `cmd /c` command. A revised piece of code:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

:start_python_files
start "1st" "cmd /c test1.py"
start "2nd" "cmd /c test2.py"
start "3rd" "cmd /c test3.py"

:check_python_files
call:infinite 1st test1.py
call:infinite 2nd test2.py
call:infinite 3rd test3.py
goto:check_python_files

:infinite
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %1" | findstr /c:PID > nul
rem findstr /c:PID command added above to confirm that tasklist has found the process (errorlevel = 0). If not (errorlevel = 1).
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (start "%1" "cmd /c %2")
```

I have just added only a `cmd /c` extra (and remove `%2`) from window title as it was not needed.

`cmd /c` tells system to run a new cmd which will carry out the command specified by string and then it will terminate.

Synopsis:

1. **Commands should be run to get more information about how they work**:

   - `call /?`
   - `start /?`
   - `goto /?`
   - `tasklist /?`
   - `findstr /?`
   - `cmd /?`

I suggest to run the above in a fresh new cmd window.

2. **Some interesting references**:

   - https://ss64.com/nt/start.html
   - [How do I pass command line parameters to a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-do-i-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)
   - [Set Windows command-line terminal title in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387276/set-windows-command-line-terminal-title-in-python)

I am really sorry for putting you into this mess. In anyway, thank you for providing such good information for me to understand where I was wrong.