# Batch that monitors and restarts a python

Tags: python, batch-file, restart

I'm trying to make a batch that restarts my python files whenever any of them close or crash, with the following command:

```
@echo off
:a
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\testfolder
test1.py
test2.py
test2.py
goto a
```

but it is not working, what should I do?

Comment: You asked this same question yesterday and were asked to clarify your problem.

Comment: @Squashman I thank you for helping me with this topic, and to make it clear, only restart when it is forced to close for some reason.
In none of the topics gave me a clear answer, and the question is very simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of an "infinite loop" which is needed in your case and python files will overload your CPU a lot I think. Have a revised piece of code (working only in single file extensions (`*.bat, *.txt`)). See below for something more general.

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

:start_python_files
start "1st" "test1.py"
start "2nd" "test2.py"
start "3rd" "test3.py"

:check_python_files
call:infinite 1st test1.py
call:infinite 2nd test2.py
call:infinite 3rd test3.py
goto:check_python_files

:infinite
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %1 - %2" | findstr /c:PID > nul
rem findstr /c:PID command added above to confirm that tasklist has found the process (errorlevel = 0). If not (errorlevel = 1).
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (start "%1" "%2")
```

Well, this way may last some time, so if a file is closed (~2-3 secs depending on your CPU overload).

Explanation:

- I enable extensions (`setlocal EnableExtensions`) to change `call` command as follows:

> CALL command now accepts labels as the target of the CALL. The syntax
> is:

> CALL :label arguments

<sup>From `call /?` command. You should type it in a fresh cmd for more information</sup>

- I specify the window title with the `start` command, so my code will work. Type `start /?` in a fresh cmd window.
- I `call` the `infinite` subroutine sending to it arguments (window title and filename). These can be accessed with `%1` (first argument) and `%2` (second argument).
- In the `infinite` subroutine, I search for window title (`WINDOWTITLE`) EQUAL (`eq`) to format `window title - filename`. Even if it doesn't exist `tasklist` will return `errorlevel` value `0` with the message:

> INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

As here `PID` string doesn't exist (if it is found it will exist), we put `findstr` to search for it. If found, `errorlevel` will be `0`. Else, it would be `1`.

- If the `errorlevel` is `1`, that means that process not found, which means that the file is closed. So, we reopen it with the arguments sent (`start "window title (%1)" "filename (%2)"`).
- As we have `call`ed the `infinite` subroutine, after its end, we will return to `check_python_files` subroutine doing all of these above infinitely, until user termination or computer shutdown.

As later discussed in chat, when we run python files standardly (with `start "window title"`) window title will be the full path to `python.exe` file. I found a way to fix it: `start` the `cmd /c` command. A revised piece of code:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

:start_python_files
start "1st" "cmd /c test1.py"
start "2nd" "cmd /c test2.py"
start "3rd" "cmd /c test3.py"

:check_python_files
call:infinite 1st test1.py
call:infinite 2nd test2.py
call:infinite 3rd test3.py
goto:check_python_files

:infinite
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %1" | findstr /c:PID > nul
rem findstr /c:PID command added above to confirm that tasklist has found the process (errorlevel = 0). If not (errorlevel = 1).
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (start "%1" "cmd /c %2")
```

I have just added only a `cmd /c` extra (and remove `%2`) from window title as it was not needed.

`cmd /c` tells system to run a new cmd which will carry out the command specified by string and then it will terminate.

References:

- https://ss64.com/nt/start.html
- [How can I pass arguments to a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-do-i-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)
- [Set Windows command-line terminal title in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387276/set-windows-command-line-terminal-title-in-python)