# How to change the title of the window in pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I create a exe file of a python script with this command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile Time.py --icon 1.ico --onefile
```

How can I change the title of EXE file window?

I don't use any tools such as kivy, Tkinter, Arcade, Pygame, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once converted with Pyinstaller, a window title can't be changed. Edit it in your `.py` code.

With Tkinter:

```
win = tk.TK()
win.title("Some Title")
```

With Pygame:

```
caption = pygame.display.set_caption('Some Title')
```

With Kivy:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Some Title'
```

With Arcade:

```
arcade.open_window(600, 600, "Some Title")
```

Glad if any of those help.

Edit: If you meant a change of the title on a live command prompt you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387276/set-windows-command-line-terminal-title-in-python) discussion out.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to any of the choices in @peki 's answer, you may use the `ctypes` module that would be more light-weighted:

```py
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("Some Title")
```