# How to change the title bar text for an application window for pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've created an exe using pyinstaller. She's a 10 but she does this on her title bar:
[image: not a 10 behavior]

Sometimes those numbers change and results in some quick flashes across the bar. Is there any way to make it just the name of the exe?

I've stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061472/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-window-in-pyinstaller#:%7E:text=Once%20converted%20with%20Pyinstaller%2C%20a,py%20code.&text=Glad%20if%20any%20of%20those%20help.). While I'd like to be able to use the `ctypes` solution (which may or may not work), I don't want to be potentially bound to a windows only solution. So I've tried using the pygame and tkinter solution. Pygame results in the application not loading and tkinter doesn't affect it at all. I haven't tried the Kivy solution, because last time I tried to install Kivy, it was a headache and ended with failure... and I decided to not hate myself today. I've also looked around in the documentation, and haven't found anything on this either. So, what must I do to change the title bar to some desired, short text?

Maybe also worth mentioning is that I build the app from the command prompt using and that it is just a standard console app:

`pyinstaller myapp.py --noconfirm --uac-admin --collect-all somepackage --add-data "a_dll.dll";. --clean --name myapp`

By standard console app, I mean you should be able to recreate this problem simply by doing:

**myapp.py**

```
print("Hello World.")
input("Say something: ")
```

and compiling it with the same parameters as mentioned above.